# How do I prevent a user from transferring a token in their wallet originating from a token mint I own or have authority on?

Tags: token, spl-token, transfer, mint

Let us say a user has claimed a token reward or has received an airdrop from my token mint that I am the owner / have authority of. Can I freeze or prevent this user from transferring or selling the token until a specified date or indefinitely?

If I do not want a user to transfer tokens from their wallet that originate from my token mint, until a certain time period, how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Token program allows you to create tokens with `--enable-freeze` flag and then you use `spl-token freeze` command to freeze any token account and then `spl-token thaw` to thaw an account.

If you don't care about showing them in their wallet, you can use some vesting protocols to distribute your tokens.

https://spl.solana.com/token#freezing-accounts